# email list of events on calendar

Tags: email, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

In office 2013 and/or Office365, is there a way to parse a calendar, and email all the events that are scheduled on a particular day?

***Example***
I'd like to get an email every day with a list of all the events I have scheduled for the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like [this](http://www.gregthatcher.com/Scripts/VBA/Outlook/GetListOfCalendarAppointments.aspx) is a good start? It produces a list of appointments and events that occur in your calendar and writes it to the body of an email.

It runs as a macro in VBA. I tested it out and it still seems to work. It gives a lot of information which you can edit by commenting. Although it produces an email it doesn't do it automatically or send it but I think this is a start.

1. Display the [developer tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx)
2. Press Alt-F11 to open the VBA editor
3. Right click in the left pane and add a module
4. Paste in the code
5. Return to the main outlook window and developer tab
6. Click macros and select your macro to run

Comment: That is a good start - I have never done anything with VB, so I guess this will be my start. I'll need to modify it a bit, but thanks a lot